Using vanilla JS to manipulate Alpine JS x-data variables on Livewire event
I have a Livewire modal, that when closed, I am firing an event, and trying to change an Alpine.JS x-data variable, uploading, to false from true.
The entire concept is a document page, there is a button that opens a modal window with a form to upload a document. I want to capture the closing of the modal without saving the document, and remove the file, and reset the modal state to before the file was uploaded. I have managed to fire an even when the close button is clicked, I have captured the event and now just need to know how to access the Alpine data variables. Here is some code to clarify.
This is the file with the button, the modal window (frame) and the call to the livewire component that makes up the actual form inside.
<div>
    <div class="card custom-card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2>
                Create a document
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue btn-sm" data-hs-overlay="#upload-document-modal">
                Upload document <i class="fe fe-upload"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="upload-document-modal" class="hs-overlay hidden size-full fixed top-0 start-0 z-[80] overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto pointer-events-none [--tab-accessibility-limited:true] [--overlay-backdrop:static]" data-hs-overlay-keyboard="false">
        <div class="hs-overlay-open:mt-7 hs-overlay-open:opacity-100 hs-overlay-open:duration-500 mt-0 opacity-0 ease-out transition-all w-3/4 m-3 sm:mx-auto min-h-[calc(100%-3.5rem)] flex items-center">
            <div class="w-full flex flex-col bg-white border shadow-sm rounded-xl pointer-events-auto dark:bg-neutral-800 dark:border-neutral-700 dark:shadow-neutral-700/70">
                <div class="flex justify-between items-center py-3 px-4 border-b dark:border-neutral-700">
                    <h3 class="font-bold text-gray-800 dark:text-white">
                        Upload document
                    </h3>
                    <button type="button" id="document-upload-modal-close" class="flex justify-center items-center size-7 text-sm font-semibold rounded-full border border-transparent text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-neutral-700" data-hs-overlay="#upload-document-modal">
                        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        <svg class="flex-shrink-0 size-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                            <path d="M18 6 6 18"></path>
                            <path d="m6 6 12 12"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="p-4 overflow-y-auto">
                    <livewire:employee.documents.create-modal :client="$client"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:initialized', () => {
            HSOverlay.autoInit()
            const el = HSOverlay.getInstance('#upload-document-modal')
            Livewire.on('document-upload-completed', (documentId) => {
                HSOverlay.close('#upload-document-modal');

                @this.set('document_id', documentId.documentId)
            })

            document.querySelector('#document-upload-modal-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
                Livewire.dispatch('document-upload-cancelled');
            })
        })
    </script>
</div>

This is the form script
<div>
    <form wire:submit="store" novalidate autocomplete="off">
        <div class=""
             x-data="{ uploading: false, progress: 0, name: '', type: '', size: 0 }"
             x-on:livewire-upload-start="uploading = true"
             x-on:livewire-upload-finish="uploading = true"
             x-on:livewire-upload-cancel="uploading = false"
             x-on:livewire-upload-error="uploading = false"
             x-on:livewire-upload-progress="progress = $event.detail.progress"
        >
            <div class="form-grid">
                <div class="cols-3">
                    <label for="document-categories-id" class="input-label">Category</label>
                    <select id="document-categories-id" wire:model.live="document_category_id" class="input">
                        <option></option>
                        @foreach ($documentCategories as $id => $documentCategory)
                            <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $documentCategory }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('document_category')" class="text-xs text-red-500 mt-2"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cols-3">
                    <x-input id="title" model="title" label="Title" />
                </div>
                <div class="cols-6">
                    <x-input id="description" model="description" label="Description" />
                </div>
                <div class="cols-3">
                    <label for="file" class="input-label">Choose file</label>
                    <input type="file" id="file" class="block w-full border border-gray-200 rounded-lg text-sm focus:z-10 focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:bg-neutral-900 dark:border-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-400
                        file:bg-gray-50 file:border-0
                        file:me-4
                        file:py-2 file:px-4
                        dark:file:bg-neutral-700 dark:file:text-neutral-400"
                           wire:model.live="file"
                           x-ref="file"
                           x-on:change='
                            name = $el.files[0].name
                            let longType = $el.files[0].type
                            size = $el.files[0].size
                            console.log(longType)
                            switch (longType) {
                                case "text/csv":
                                    type = "csv"
                                    break;
                                case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":
                                    type = "excel"
                                    break;
                                case "application/pdf":
                                    type = "pdf"
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    type = ""
                                    break;
                            }
                        '
                    >
                    <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('file')" class="text-xs text-red-500 mt-2"/>
                </div>
                <div class="cols-6">
                    <!-- File Uploading Progress Form -->
                    <div x-cloak x-show="uploading">
                        <!-- Uploading File Content -->
                        <div class="mb-2 flex justify-between items-center">
                            <div class="flex items-center gap-x-3">
                                    <span class="size-8 flex justify-center items-center border border-gray-200 text-gray-500 rounded-lg dark:border-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-500">
                                        <div x-show="type === ''">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('build/assets/img/media/document-icon.svg') }}" alt="File type icon" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div x-show="type === 'csv'">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('build/assets/img/media/csv-icon.svg') }}" alt="File type icon" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div x-show="type === 'excel'">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('build/assets/img/media/excel-icon.svg') }}" alt="File type icon" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div x-show="type === 'pdf'">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('build/assets/img/media/pdf-icon.png') }}" alt="File type icon" />
                                        </div>
                                    </span>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white" id="filename" x-text="name"></p>
                                    <p class="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-neutral-500" x-text="Math.round(size / 10240) / 100 + ' MB'"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inline-flex items-center gap-x-2">
                                <div x-show="progress < 100">
                                    <a class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-800 dark:text-neutral-500 dark:hover:text-neutral-200" href="#" wire:click="$cancelUpload('file')">
                                        <svg class="flex-shrink-0 size-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                            <path d="M3 6h18"></path>
                                            <path d="M19 6v14c0 1-1 2-2 2H7c-1 0-2-1-2-2V6"></path>
                                            <path d="M8 6V4c0-1 1-2 2-2h4c1 0 2 1 2 2v2"></path>
                                            <line x1="10" x2="10" y1="11" y2="17"></line>
                                            <line x1="14" x2="14" y1="11" y2="17"></line>
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div x-show="progress === 100">
                                    <a class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-800 dark:text-neutral-500 dark:hover:text-neutral-200" href="#" x-on:click='
                                        $refs.file.value = ""
                                        uploading = false
                                        progress = 0
                                        name = ""
                                        type = ""
                                        size = 0
                                    '>
                                        <svg class="flex-shrink-0 size-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                            <path d="M3 6h18"></path>
                                            <path d="M19 6v14c0 1-1 2-2 2H7c-1 0-2-1-2-2V6"></path>
                                            <path d="M8 6V4c0-1 1-2 2-2h4c1 0 2 1 2 2v2"></path>
                                            <line x1="10" x2="10" y1="11" y2="17"></line>
                                            <line x1="14" x2="14" y1="11" y2="17"></line>
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Uploading File Content -->

                        <!-- Progress Bar -->
                        <div class="flex items-center gap-x-3 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="flex w-full h-2 bg-gray-200 rounded-full overflow-hidden dark:bg-neutral-700" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                <div class="flex flex-col justify-center rounded-full overflow-hidden bg-blue-600 text-xs text-white text-center whitespace-nowrap transition duration-500 dark:bg-blue-500" x-bind:style="{width: progress + '%'}"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-6 text-end">
                                <span class="text-sm text-gray-800 dark:text-white" x-text="progress + '%'"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Progress Bar -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- End File Uploading Progress Form -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer flex justify-end">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-green btn-sm mx-0.5 rounded disabled:bg-green-200 hover:disabled:bg-green-200" id="document-create" x-bind:disabled=" progress < 100" >
                    Save <i class="fe fe-save"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    @script
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:initialized', () => {
            let fileInput = $wire.el.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
            Livewire.on('document-upload-cancelled', () => {
                document.addEventListener('alpine.init', () => {
                    Alpine.data.uploading = false
                })
                console.log('???')
                fileInput.value = ""
                $wire.progress = 0
                $wire.data.uploading = false
            })
        })
    </script>
    @endscript
</div>

I have read through the documentation, and can see where you can use Alpine.data() to create a reusable component, but that is not what I am looking for here.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Utilized the documentation HERE

Found the answer moments after asking...
The answer if anyone were to need it, is $wire.entangle() on the x-data properties.
